# Dial up internet using Android

Tags: networking, internet

I still remember the old way of creating Dial up connection using our mobile device as a modem to connect internet. Is it possible to use our android device as a dial up modem to connect internet? Thank you.
P.S Please avoid mentioning USB tethering as an alternative solution.